# How much of Stephen King's work is based on Lovecraft's works?

Tags: h-p-lovecraft, stephen-king

I heard that Stephen King based some of his work on Lovecraft, who based some of his work on E. A. Poe.

Does anyone know which works of King's were based on H. P. Lovecraft?

Comment: I really don't know if this question has an answer. I think only King hinself would be able to answer. A better question would be asking which of King's novels have similarities to Lovecrafts works, but that question would be best ascked in the chat room.

Comment: Thanks. I assume some of similarities will also be accidental. Still, I hope that perhaps somebody has an estimate.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris King has made public statements, and the occurrence of Lovecraftian names and themes in his books speak for themselves. Why should this question be unanswerable?

Comment: On a semi-related note... Pet Sematary features the Wendigo, which is also the title of a story by [Algernon Blackwood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algernon_Blackwood), though this concept comes from Native American legend.  I would consider Blackwood as a contemporary of Lovecraft, and an inspiration, [see Lovecraft's essay](http://www.hplovecraft.com/writings/texts/essays/shil.aspx)

Answer (score 12):

A lot of this is answered by [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_King). For instance (according to his autobiography *Danse Macabre*), Lovecraftian themes (such as the [*Necronomicon*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necronomicon) or characters such as [Yog-Sothoth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yog-Sothoth)) occur by name in King books such as [*Gramma*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramma_%28short_story%29), [*‘Salem’s Lot*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%27Salem%27s_Lot), [*I Know What You Need*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Know_What_You_Need). Furthermore, [*It*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It_%28novel%29) is quite obviously influenced by Lovecraft.

[Cthulhu mythos in popular culture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cthulhu_Mythos_in_popular_culture) lists more Stephen King works that are based in the Lovecraftian Cthulhu setting.

Answer (score 3):

The short story "Jerusalem's Lot" in the collection ***Night Shift*** by Stephen King, is very Lovecraftian in tone and inspiration.  From the cursed grimoire to the to the climactic monster burrowing up through the church floor, it could have been written by HPL himself.